# How change join to semaphore

Tags: java, concurrency

How can I get functionality of `join()` from `Thread` class using `Semaphore`?

I mean I want wait for other threads.

Comment: You want to see what join() do or you want to make your thread to wait for other to finish ?

Comment: @Kamen, I want to stop thread until other will not end

Comment: You have t1 and t2. t1 should wait for t2 to finish. So at the point where t1 should wait just write t2.join() and that's it. The execution will stop at that line until t2 finishes.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I summise that you want to do what `Thread.join()` does without using `Thread.join()` but using a `Semaphore`. I can think of some reasons you might want to do this, but I feel that you probably just want to use `join()`. However, here goes.

Let's start with what `join()` does - taken from the javadocs

```
Waits for this thread to die
```

By which we can assume it means stop running. Okay, so what we will need is a `Semaphore` that has a permit that is released when the thread dies. Let us assume that you can modify the two threads in question i.e. they're not final. You can then override their `run` methods so that the first releases the semaphore when it's finished and the second waits for the semaphore to be released before it starts i.e.

```
final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);
Thread t1 = new MyThreadOne(){
  {
    try{
      sem.acquire();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){ log(...); }
  }
  @Override
  public void run(){        
    super.run();
    sem.release();
  }
};
Thread t2  new MyThreadTwo(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    try{
      sem.acquire();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){ log(...); }
    super.run();
  }
};
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

You might want to pass the semaphore into the constructor if your example requires it, or have it accessed in some other way. Note that `sem` has to be `final` here as it's referenced in an anonymous inner class and Java doesn't do closures properly.